# Is there a way to insert the current date in Notes?

Tags: ios

In iOS8, is there an easy way to insert the current date (or current date/time) in Notes?

Comment: You could make a script with Xcode... Simple. If you need, I will include code in final answer. I am on iPad, so I can't do it now

Comment: I have no idea how to make a script with xcode, get it onto my phone, or run it. If you can provide any such details, that would be awesome -- thanks!

Comment: I ain't on my computer now, so I will paste something once I can :)

Comment: What about macOS ?

Answer (score 1):

[Late Post - posting in case it helps anyone else]

On iPhone (iOS 11+), the "[Insert Date Keyboard](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/insert-date-keyboard/id1299487447?mt=8)" provides an easy way to insert the current date in Notes or any other app. If you want to include the current Time in Notes as well, the date format (under advanced settings) would be something like: "yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm"

*Note: The app costs a dollar*

*( Disclaimer: I helped work on this )*

Comment: Sadly this is not available in App Store (anymore?) … why? Any alternative?